# How can I mock the listBlobsByHierarchy method in jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, azure-blob-storage

I'm writing unit tests for a function that is going to iterate through the blobs in a storage container. I'm currently having issues mocking out the listBlobsByHierarchy method using jest and jest-mock-extended. Are there any code examples on how to do this? My implementation isn't complete, but the behavior I want is to mock the implementation of listBlobsByHierarchy to return an expected BlobItem. I'm trying to return a mocked ContainerListBlobHierarchySegmentResponse, but I'm not sure how to attach the expected blobItem to this and I'm not sure how to mock that response correctly.

Here is what I have so far.

Method I'm testing:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { ContainerListBlobsOptions } from "@azure/storage-blob";
import { getStorageContainerClient } from "../blobStorage/BlobStorage";
import { ImageInfo } from "../common/types";
import { handleError } from "../cosmos/CosmosContext";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> 
{
    try
    {
        const containerClient = await getStorageContainerClient();
        if(req.method === "GET")
        {
            const imageinfo: ImageInfo[] = [];
            const containerListBlobsOptions: ContainerListBlobsOptions = 
            {
                includeDeleted: true,
                includeMetadata: true
            };
            for await (const item of containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/", containerListBlobsOptions))
            {
                if (item.kind === "prefix")
                {
                    context.log("Prefix type:");
                    context.log(item.name);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.log(item.name);
                    context.log(item.deleted);
                    context.log(item.properties);
                }
                
            }
            // Get a block blob client
            // const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(tenantBlobName);
            // const properties = await blockBlobClient.getProperties();
            context.res = { status: 200 };
            // context.res = { status: 200, body: JSON.stringify(properties)};
            return;
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        handleError(context, err);
    }
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

My test so far:

```
jest.mock("../../blobStorage/BlobStorage");
import { HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import * as imageinfoFunction from "../../imageinfo/index";
import { context } from "../data/setupData";
import { BlobItem, ContainerClient, ContainerListBlobHierarchySegmentResponse } from "@azure/storage-blob";
import * as BlobStorage from "../../blobStorage/BlobStorage";
import { mock } from "jest-mock-extended";
import { ImageInfo } from "../../common/types";

describe("Image info tests", () => 
{
    const getReq: HttpRequest = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "localhost.com",
        headers: {"a": "b"},
        query: {},
        params: {"a": "b"},
    };

    const mockStorageContainerClient = mock<ContainerClient>();
    const getStorageContainerClientSpy = jest.spyOn(BlobStorage, "getStorageContainerClient");
    getStorageContainerClientSpy.mockImplementation(async () => mockStorageContainerClient );
    
    afterEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());
    test("Calling image info function should return an array of image infos", async () => 
    {
        const listBlobsByHierarchySpy = jest.spyOn(mockStorageContainerClient, "listBlobsByHierarchy");
        const thumbnail: Buffer = Buffer.from("test");
        const imageInfo: ImageInfo = 
        {
            filename: "file",
            mimeType: "image/jpeg",
            thumbnail,
            thumbnailUrl: "thumbnail.url",
            url: "imageUrl",
            user: "user",
            size: thumbnail.length,
            createdOn: new Date("09/09/2020"),
            deleted: false
        };
        const listBlobsByHierarchyResponse: ContainerListBlobHierarchySegmentResponse = mock<ContainerListBlobHierarchySegmentResponse>();
        const blobItem: BlobItem = 
        {
            name: "file",
            deleted: false,
            snapshot: "snapshot",
            metadata: { user: "user"},
            properties: 
            {
                lastModified: new Date("09/09/2020"),
                etag: "etag",
                createdOn: new Date("09/09/2020"),
                contentLength: thumbnail.length,
                contentType: "image/jpeg"
            }
        };
        listBlobsByHierarchySpy.mockResolvedValue(() => listBlobsByHierarchyResponse);
        const expectedResult: ImageInfo[] = [imageInfo];
        await imageinfoFunction.default(context, getReq);
        if (context.res != undefined)
        {
            expect(context.res.body).toEqual(JSON.stringify(expectedResult)); 
        }
        else
        {
            fail("context.res should not be undefined");
        }
    });
});
```

```
listBlobsByHierarchySpy.mockResolvedValue(() => listBlobsByHierarchyResponse);
```

Is giving the following error:
Argument of type '() => ContainerListBlobHierarchySegmentResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
[image]

I've tried:

```
// Gives the same error as above
listBlobsByHierarchySpy.mockResolvedValue(async() => listBlobsByHierarchyResponse);

// Says that it is missing a bunch of properties which make it hard to mock
listBlobsByHierarchySpy.mockImplementation(async() => listBlobsByHierarchyResponse);
```

Any help would be appreciated!